# How to continue using a powershell script after it finished

Tags: powershell

I don't know much about scripting at all, but want to help out my lead with something. I'm trying to create a script that will ask for a username and it will return when their password will expire in AD. I also want to continue inputting usernames after it has finished in case there are multiple users I need to check. Below is the script I have so far.

```
$User = Read-Host "Username?"
Get-ADUser $User -Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
Select-Object -Property "Displayname", @{Name = "ExpiryDate"; Expression = {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

I was looking into doing loops, but I do not know how to write it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`do-until` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_do):

```
do {
    $User = Read-Host "Username? (enter 'q!' to quit)"
    if($User -notin @('', 'q!')){
        Get-ADUser $User -Properties DisplayName,"msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Select-Object -Property Displayname, @{Name = "ExpiryDate"; Expression = {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
    }
} until ($User -eq 'q!')
```

PowerShell will continue to repeat the code inside the `do` block as long as the user doesn't input `q!`. The `if` statement also prevents attempts to fetch a user when no username was provided.

Comment: After trying and testing it out the results only show up after I type 'q!'  I tried to position the loop in different parts of the script and could not seem to get it to work. Is there a way for it to show the results after each input before starting the loop again?

Comment: @adamring Sure, add `| Out-Host` (or `| Out-Default`) at the end of the `Get-ADUser` statement :)

Comment: Thanks so much that worked. Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a while loop

```
while ($true) {
    $User = Read-Host "Username?"
    Get-ADUser $User -Properties "DisplayName","msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Select-Object -Property "Displayname", @{Name = "ExpiryDate"; Expression = {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
    
    if ($User -eq "q!") {
        break
        
    }
    
}
```

To quit the while loop enter "q!" in place of a user.